# Java Regex (No White Space or 0-9)

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

Input, via a question, the report owner’s first name as a string.

Need a regular expression to check, conditionally, to make sure the first name doesn’t contain any numeric characters, numbers between 0 – 9.  If it does you must remove it.  The first name can not contain any white space either.

```
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter your FIRST name:");
        firstName = keyboard.next();
        firstName= firstName.toUpperCase();
    }

    while( !firstName.matches("^/s^[a-zA-Z]+$/s"));

    System.out.println("Thanks " + firstName);
```

---

```
Output
p
Please enter your FIRST name:
p p
Please enter your FIRST name:
Please enter your FIRST name:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got your regex muddled up. Try this:

```
while(!firstName.matches("^[^\\d\\s]+$"));
```

The regex `"^[^\\d\\s]+$"` means "non digits or whitespace, and at least one character"

Comment: But you mustn't forget those French, African and other exotic countries' first names which can have at least "'" in their first name. I'm sure there are other odd characters, but I'm just stating a few.

Comment: @Lopina Good point. I've changed the regex to *exclude* rather than *include*, so this being Bastille Day, vive la France!

Comment: Nice one, definitely cleaner than my own solution :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate digits, just force:

```
\D*
```

In your matcher

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: `^[a-zA-Z,.'-]+$`. :D

Also, if you want to try out your regular expressions, [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/) is a great place for that :D

You used Scanner#next, instead of Scanner#nextLine.

From Scanner#next JavaDoc:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern.

I believe one such delimiter is `\s+` :D

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstNameParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstName = null;

        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter your FIRST name: ");
            firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
            firstName = firstName.toUpperCase();
        }

        while (!firstName.matches("^[a-zA-Z,.'-]+$"));

        System.out.println("Thanks " + firstName);

    }
}
```

Comment: How about the white space though. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: If you copy-pase my regex into rubular, and try to write a name with a whitespace, it will tell you that it doesn't match that :D

Comment: O_o. Are you absolutely sure you have copied my regex as it is?

Comment: 'do
  {
   System.out.println("Please enter your FIRST name:");
   firstName = keyboard.next();
   firstName= firstName.toUpperCase();
  }
  while( !firstName.matches("^[a-zA-Z,.'-]+$"));
  
  
  System.out.println("Thanks " + firstName);'

Comment: Welcome. This program will assist you in generating a report...
Please enter your FIRST name:
p p
Thanks P

Answer (score 0):

As you have `firstname` in uppercase and `matches` method matches the whole input, 
`[A-Z]+` is sufficient.

```
while( !firstName.matches("[A-Z]+"));
```

or

```
while( !firstName.matches("\\p{Lu}+"));
```

Comment: verify your regex part where you might have space

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
firstName =  firstName.replaceAll("[\\d\\s]", "").toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  Created it using [Rubular.com](http://rubular.com/). The

```
Pattern nameRequirment = Pattern.compile("^((?!.[\\d\\s]).)*$");

while (!nameRequirement.matcher(myString).matches()){
  //... prompt for new name
}
```